# C Programming - type in the program that copies a file using line-at-a-time I/O (fgets and fputs) but use a MAXLINE of 4

Tags: c, buffer, fgets, fputs

I apologize in advance because I just started learning C. This is my code so far.

```
int main ()
{
char buf [4];
// open the file
FILE *fp = fopen("readme","r");

// Return if could not open file
if (fp == NULL)
    return 0;

while(fgets(buf,4,fp) != NULL){

    // Checking for end of file
    if (feof(fp))
        break ;

    fputs(buf,stdout);
}  while(1);

fclose(fp);
return(0);
}
```

Im having trouble getting the results I need. I assume that setting a buffer to 4 would likely return the first four characters of each line. I could be wrong but Ive been stuck on this a few hours trying to figure out how to Overflow the Buffer. Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: The file is being read correctly and properly printed I just feel like the "fgets" or misunderstanding of the buffer is where im messing up.

Comment: What is your question? What is this program supposed to do, what is it doing instead?

Comment: If the line (including the newline character) is longer than 3 , then `fgets` will only read 3 bytes. The next `fgets` will read again up to 3 bytes and so on.

Comment: ` while(1);`. This is an infinite loop. You don't need this.

Comment: Please read the man page for `feof`. It is different from the same-name function in, say, PHP. In C it tells you if an attempt was made to read past the end of a file, so it is an error condition. In PHP it tells when you reached end of file. In C your loop control `while(fgets(buf,4,fp) != NULL)` will not try to read from past the end of the file, so `feof` is of no use here.

Comment: `char buf [4];` can only hold **3** characters because `fgets` always supplies the C "string" nul terminator. Your hope that the code will show the first 4 characters of each line is also false, because when the buffer limit is reached, the rest of the line is not skipped, but the next 4 (actually 3) characters will be read by the next `fgets`.

Comment: @Barmar This is the assignment I was given. Its very vague but im trying to understand what occurs when a buffer is shorter than the given input.

Comment: @barmar - "type in the program that copies a file using line-at-a-time I/O (fgets and fputs) from Figure 5.5 (fgets.cpp) but use a MAXLINE of 4. What happens if you copy lines that exceed this length? Explain what is happening"

Comment: @weathervane so why is it return my file entirely? thats my big question. Wouldn't my strings be cut short or what not?

Comment: See the good answer, and please read the man page for functions before asking. They were written: for **you**.

Comment: @EricRawls You should put that in the question (and not just the title). And the question needs to explain what you think is going wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to overflow the buffer? If you want to do that, just set the `size` argument to `fgets()` larger than the size of `buf`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not understanding how `fgets` works.

`fgets` will read up to 3 characters (and not 4, because `fgets` '\0'-terminates the buffer). If the newline `'\n'` is among these 3,
`fgets` will stop reading and writes the newline and returns, otherwise it
continues until the buffer is full.

Let's say the input is: `This is a very long line\nThis is another line\n`,
then `fgets` will read the first 3 characters and store `'T'`, `'h'`, `'i'`,
`'\0` in the buffer. The next time `fgets` reads the next 3 characters:
`'s'`, `' '`, `'i'` and store them in the buffer. Eventually it will reach to
the first newline, and stops reading there.

In general `fgets` will try to read the max number of characters that the buffer can hold.
If the newline is among these characters, it stops reading and writes the newline
in the buffer as well. If the newline is **not** found among them, then `fgets` will
stop when the buffer is full.

Whether `fgets` reads a whole line depends on the size of the buffer, so even
with two consecutive calls of `fgets`, you might not still getting the whole
line, as I showed you with the example above. That's why your assumption
*I assume that setting a buffer to 4 would likely return the first four
characters of each line* is wrong.

The only way to know if `fgets` read a whole line is looking whether the newline was written in the buffer.

Also note that

```
if (feof(fp))
    break ;
```

is not needed here, because `fgets` will return `NULL` when the end-of-file is
reached and no more characters can be read, the loop will end anyway, so doing
the extra check is pointeless.

And this

```
while(fgets(buf,4,fp) != NULL){
    ...
} while(1);
```

is the same as this:

```
while(fgets(buf,4,fp) != NULL){
    ...
}

while(1);
```

So after reading the whole file, you are entering in an endless loop.

Comment: Wow thanks very much! You cleared up a few things I wasn't sure about.

Comment: I suspect the extra `while(1)` is because he started with a `do-while` loop with `feof()` check and `break`, changed it to a `while` loop, but forgot to remove the `feof()` and second `while`.

Comment: @Barmar that was my guess too.